# clearInterval and setInterval in javascript Instantly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
```

Main Function:

```
var interval;                     
function refreshId(session_to_user) {
interval = setInterval(function()
{
$('.chat-box').load("<?php echo base_url()."users/message/refresh_div/"; ?>" + session_to_user);
}, 10000);
}
```

in this main function I'm only going to perform my requirement here. I have a variable interval my enabling this function, and it will refresh every 10 seconds.

onclick of function

```
forloop
{   
<a href = "" onclick="myFunction(user_id)"
}   

function myFunction(user_id){      
clearInterval(interval); 
$.ajax({                        
success:function(data)
{     
    $('.chats').html(data);
}
})   
refreshId(session_to_user);  
}
```

If anyone clicks on href, it should clearInterval if already exists else a new Interval has to be established on click function. In my current code, it works if I click for the first time. It starts refreshing the first link for every 10 seconds, but when I click for the second time on the second link, it waits. Still, the first one gets executed and then the second one is executing. My requirement is if I click, the established setInterval has to stopped instantly and the new one has to be started on the spot same as for my next function paper_plane() also.

```
function paper_plane()
{  
clearInterval(interval); 
$.ajax({
 success:function(html)
{
$('#chat').append(html);
$('.chat-input').val('');
$('.chat-input').focus();
}
});
}
var side_bar_path = "<?php echo base_url()."users/message/load_side_bar"; ?>";
$.ajax({
success : function(data)
{
$('.msg-list').html(data);
}
});
refreshId(session_to_user); 
}
```

Comment: could you replicate this on plunker/fiddle?

Comment: Nothing shown would indicate the `clearInterval()` won't do as you intend it to do. As mentioned; a demo that replicates problem would help

Comment: when you clicked the second link to clear interval  did you do it after 10 seconds was elapsed or before  ?

Comment: @dreamweiver I'm clicking on the second link after clicking the first link so the first setInterval will be elaspsed when i click the second link it waits tills the first setInterval to be completed and then the second one gets executed

Comment: That's obvious because when first set interval was triggered it made a Ajax call to server which would not return response immediately, so its not possible to cancel that call after 10 sec has elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can cancel the ajax request after the delay(10 seconds) is elapsed from `first click handler`,since it would not return the result immediately.

so the only way you can cancel the previous ajax calls before making a new ajax call is to `suppress/ignore` the responses of the previous ajax calls once the second link is triggered, this way you will create a scenario what your expecting.

Below i have created a small snippet which will do the scenario mentioned above.

**JS Code:**

```
 var firstTimer;
//first click handler
$('#first').on('click',function () {

  firstTimer= setInterval(function (){
              $.ajax({
                 url:"http://target.org/page.html",
                 dataType: "POST",
                 data:{'name1':'davy'}
                 success: function(data) {
                     //suppress the response when timer is stopped. 
                     if(firstTimer>0){
                        return;
                     }    
                     //if timer is not stopped process the data    
                 },
                 error :function(error) {
                     //handle error
                 }     
              });
          },1000);
});

//second click handler
$('#second').on('click',function () {
  //clear the firstTimer before staring a new timer
  clearInterval(firstTimer);
  var timer;
  timer = setInterval(function (){
              $.ajax({
                 url:"http://target.org/page2.html",
                 dataType: "POST",
                 data:{'name1':'rog'}
                 success: function(data) {
                    //process the data 
                 },
                 error :function(error) {
                     //handle error
                 }    
              });
          },1000);
});
```